# RxCocoa RxSwift 'debounce' is deprecated: Use DispatchTimeInterval overload instead

Tags: rx-swift, rx-cocoa

How to convert deprecated debounce code to use DispatchTimeInterval?

Here is the deprecated code:

```
self.myObservable.asDriver().debounce(2).drive(onNext: {(v) in
            doSomething()
        }).disposed(by: self.disposeBag)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I expect you already solved this yourself, but...

```
self.myObservable.asDriver().debounce(.seconds(2)).drive(onNext: {(v) in
    doSomething()
}).disposed(by: self.disposeBag)
```